# z-index layered elements affecting base layer elements

Tags: html, css

[image: My current website image]
As you can see there is an image slideshow in center of the page and those two description divisions which are set to `z-index 2` but still it is been affecting the images and slideshow which doesnt have `z-index` defined
and when I removed the description divisions the slideshow gets back to normal [image: screenshot here]

So is there any way I can add those description divisions in somewhat different layer from all other elemetns and prevent it from affecting other elements in the page (also those description divisions will be appeared on clicking the buttons in menubar by default they will be hidden)

Comment: If it's moving the slideshow, it's in the same flow as the slideshow. I'm guessing you're floating those description elements when you really want to be using `position:absolute` instead.

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Yes I have been using float to keep the divisions in same line with `position:relative` and I tried removing float and setting the position to absolute and that worked very well. Thank you David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `position: absolute;` for more info since you didn't share your code's use my example:

```css
/* Giving a background-color to the nav container. */
nav {
    margin: 100px 0;
    background-color: #E64A19;
    width: 700px;
}

/* Removing padding, margin and "list-style" from the "ul",
 * and adding "position:reltive" */
nav ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    }

/* Positioning the navigation items inline */
nav ul li {
    margin: 0px -7px 0 0;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: #E64A19;
    }

/* Styling the links */
nav a {
    display:block;
    padding:0 10px;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:20px;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

/* Background color change on Hover */
nav a:hover {
    background-color: #000000;
}

/* Hide Dropdowns by Default
 * and giving it a position of absolute */
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
}

/* Display Dropdowns on Hover */
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display:inherit;
}

/* Fisrt Tier Dropdown */
nav ul ul li {
    min-width:170px;
    display:list-item;
    position: relative;
}

/* Second, Third and more Tiers
 * We move the 2nd and 3rd etc tier dropdowns to the left
 * by the amount of the width of the first tier.
*/
nav ul ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:100%;
}

/* Change ' +' in order to change the Dropdown symbol */
li > a:after { content:  ' +'; }
li > a:only-child:after { content: ''; }
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">WordPress</a>

            <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Themes</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Plugins</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>

                    <!-- Second Tier Drop Down -->
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Stuff</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Things</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Other Stuff</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- Second Tier Drop Down ends-->

                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- First Tier Drop Down ends -->

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Graphic Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I realized that the issue was position:absolute and it has been fixed thanks for your answer :)